# Why does the first EditText view not work correctly, but the ones below it do?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If a user enters text into the first EditText and then clicks return, it will clear all their text. However if a user enters text into the second EditText and clicks return, nothing happens. The first EditText will also not display text colors correctly, it displays the text color as black while the rest correctly display it as white.

Sign Up Screen

```
struct SignUpScreen: View {

    @State
    var firstName: String = ""
    @State
    var lastName: String = ""
    @State
    var birthday: String = ""
    @State
    var number: String = ""
    @State
    var email: String = ""
    @State
    var password: String = ""
    @State
    var confirmPassword: String = ""

    @ObservedObject
    var viewModel: SignUpViewModel = SignUpViewModel()


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                VClearBackground()
                Spacer()
            }
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Group {
                        PreHeaderText(header: "Get Started")
                            .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: {d in
                                d[.leading]
                            })
                            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 32, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        HeaderText(header: "Create Account")
                        EditText(hint: "John", text: $viewModel.firstName, label: "FIRST NAME", textContentType: UITextContentType.name)
                        EditText(hint: "Doe", text: $lastName, label: "LAST NAME", textContentType: UITextContentType.name)
                        EditText(hint: "01/01/2001", text: $birthday, label: "BIRTHDAY")
                        EditText(hint: "(123) 456-7890)", text: $number, label: "MOBILE NUMBER", textContentType: UITextContentType.telephoneNumber, keyboardType: UIKeyboardType.phonePad)
                        EditText(hint: "email@exmaple.com", text: $email, label: "EMAIL", textContentType: UITextContentType.emailAddress)
                        EditText(hint: "********", text: $password, label: "PASSWORD", textContentType: UITextContentType.newPassword)
                        EditText(hint: "********", text: $confirmPassword, label: "CONFIRM PASSWORD", textContentType: UITextContentType.newPassword)
                    }
                    Group {
                        if self.viewModel.error != nil {
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text(viewModel.error ?? "")
                                    .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.error.color)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            VowerButton(text: "Submit") {
                                self.viewModel.signUp(firstName: self.viewModel.firstName, lastName: self.lastName, email: self.email, birthday: self.birthday, phoneNumber: self.number, password: self.password, confirmPassword: self.confirmPassword)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding()

                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            NavigationLink(destination: LoginScreen(), isActive: $viewModel.goToLogin) {
                                CtaText(text: "Have an account?", cta: "Login") {
                                    self.viewModel.onGoToLoginClicked()
                                }
                            }
                            .padding()
                            Spacer()
                        }

                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 16, trailing: 16))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black, ColorTheme.brandPurple.color]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

EditText

```
struct EditText: View {

    var hint: String
    @Binding
    var text: String
    var label: String = ""
    var defaultValue =  ""
    var textContentType: UITextContentType? = .none
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default

    private func initializeDefaultValue() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = self.defaultValue
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        initializeDefaultValue()
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(label).font(.system(size: 12)).bold()
                .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.text.color)
            HStack {
                TextField(hint, text: $text)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .textContentType(textContentType)
                .keyboardType(keyboardType)
                    .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.text.color)
            }
            Divider().background(Color(ColorTheme.brandBlue.value))
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 12, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0))
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```
EditText(hint: "John", text: $viewModel.firstName, label: "FIRST NAME", textContentType: UITextContentType.name)
EditText(hint: "Doe", text: $lastName, label: "LAST NAME", textContentType: UITextContentType.name)
```

as you see 1st text field is bound to view model (not provided, so I can't say what's wrong there), but 2nd to internal view state.

As I see there is `firstName` as internal view state, so possible the intention was (and actual fix) just use it

```
EditText(hint: "John", text: $firstName, label: "FIRST NAME", textContentType: UITextContentType.name)
```